What is the index of $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ as a subgroup of $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$
I know that $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not normal in $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ but what is the index? The problem was studied more in general? Taking a finite extension of fields $L/F$, what can we say about the cosets of $\textrm{SL}_2(F)$ in $\textrm{SL}_2(L)$?

Note that the Lie algebra over $\Bbb C$ is a $3$-dimensional complex vector space, which is a $6$-dimensional real vector space. The quotient, then, by the Lie algebra over $\Bbb R$ is a $3$-dimensional real vector space. (By the way, your use of “over” in English is backwards.)

The index is infinite.
When $z \in \mathbf C^\times$, the matrix $M_z := (\begin{smallmatrix} z&0\\0&1/z\end{smallmatrix})$ is in ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf C)$. For $z$ and $w$ in $\mathbf C^\times$, show $M_z{\rm SL}_2(\mathbf R) = M_w{\rm SL}_2(\mathbf R)$ if and only if $z/w$ is real.  So when $z = e^{it}$ with $0 < t < \pi$ (the top of the unit circle), the matrices $M_z$ are in different left cosets of ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf R)$.

Continuum, to be more precise.
